# Django React Serving Together Page not found (404)

Tags: python, reactjs, django

I develop an application using Django and React. I want to serving Django and React together. I create an build in react. I use it in Django. This is urls.py ;

```
urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^$', views.index),
 
]
```

and views.py;

```
def index(request):
    return render(request, "build/index.html")
```

When I run development server there is no any error but when ı want to go url directly ;

http://www.x.com:8000/accounts

I got page not found (404) error.

Comment: Do you get a django error or a error from your webserver? It might be a problem with the communication between your server and python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, do you have an urlpattern for `/accounts`? If your example is complete then you get 404 because Django doesn't know what to return for `/accounts`. The only URL your Django server supports, as per your example code, is index available at `http://www.x.com:8000` (maybe even `http://www.x.com:8000/` (notice the trailing `/`) depending on your `APPEND_SLASH` settings).

You need to to add an urlapptern and view (and probably a template) for `/accounts`. Something like (not tested)

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index),
    url(r'^accounts$', views.index),
]

def accounts(request):
    return render(request, "build/accounts.html")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this is working. But I have more than one inner page, do I have to do the same for them? How can I solve with a single url path?

Comment: Yes, you have to add url patters for all your pages. I don't think it's possible with a single url pattern. Also: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.

Comment: Last question. How can do if  "http://www.x.com:8000/accounts/your_account " like this.

Comment: With `url(r'^accounts/your_account$', views.your_account),`; so again - new url, new view (and maybe even a new template). For more info pleas refer to docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/.

Comment: Yes I understand.Thanks for your help.  But how to render;  def your_account(request):
    return render(request, "X")  inside build.Which .html have to use?